# sqlite with multiple like

Tags: php, sqlite, select, sql-like

I am trying to set up a query with php and sqlite and the query has multiple LIKE conditions...

```
$findMe  = 'blah';
$nLast   = -1; 
$nRecord = 5;
$db      = new PDO('sqlite:data.db');
$qry = "SELECT *
        FROM mytable    
        WHERE (id > $nLast)     
        AND ((col1 LIKE '%$findMe%')    
        OR (col2 LIKE '%$findMe%')  
        OR (col3 LIKE '%$findMe%')  
        OR (col4 LIKE '%$findMe%'))     
        LIMIT $nRecord  
        ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $db->query($qry);
```

...but this will not return any results.  if i run the query with just one of the LIKE conditions it will work.

Comment: ...FTS is an option, but it does not seem very portable since it is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try using `glob` instead of `like`?

```
select *
from "mytable"
where ('col1' || 'col2' || 'col3' || 'col4')
glob '%$findMe%'
```

Comment: Is their any documentation available about the glob keyword? I am asking because I cannot find any information about it when searching the internet.

Comment: A quick search revealed this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_glob_clause.htm

Comment: i was avoiding GLOB because it is case-sensitive...  that being said i tried your example and it does not work for me either.  i am now wondering if i am using the parentheses correctly, can ANDs and ORs be isolated with parentheses?

Comment: @jayveesea As far as I know, ANDs and ORs can be isolated with parentheses.